# Using ColorMatrixFilter with HDividedBox in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I want to use a ColorMatrixFilter with a HDividedBox element so that the left and right boxes make the chart black & white, but leave the center section in color.

It seems like the filter would have to be on the AreaChart instead of the HDividedBox, but I was wondering if there is a way to setup the canvases to mask the content behind them.

My current code looks as follows; the grey filter has no effect.

```
<mx:HDividedBox id="dividedBox" horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
        width="100%" height="100%" 
        liveDragging="true" >
    <mx:Canvas id="leftBox" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" 
            backgroundAlpha="0.5" width="50%" 
            height="100%" />
    <mx:Canvas backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" backgroundAlpha="0" 
            width="50%" height="100%" buttonMode="true"   
            mouseDown="setMouseDown(rangeChart);" 
            minWidth="{rangeDataRatio * 4}"
    mouseUp="showAnnotations = true; refreshAnnotations()"/>
<mx:Canvas id="rightBox" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" 
    backgroundAlpha="0.5" width="0%" height="100%"
    filters="{[greyFilter]}" />
</mx:HDividedBox>
```

The filter code is as follows:

```
var greyMatrix:Array = [ 
    1,1,1,0,0,
    1,1,1,0,0,
    1,1,1,0,0,
    0,0,0,1,0 ];

var greyFilter:ColorMatrixFilter = 
    new ColorMatrixFilter(greyMatrix);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters are applied only to the contents of the object they are applied to. 
So, if you have something inside `rightBox` canvas, then it should be seen with the filter applied. But if the object is not a child of this canvas, it won't have the filter applied.

You can try using `BitmapData` object and its `draw` method to capture the image below the canvas and apply the filter to the resulting Bitmap.